# MS Dynamics return GUID for creating a record but the record is missing

Tags: api, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

We are using a third-party MS Dynamics hosting and we send data to them using Dynamics API web services "CrmService."

When we call the "Create" method it appears as though the call was success as the Dynamics server returns a GUID back to the caller.  Looking the CrmService code below it tells me that the that's exactly what I should get if there are no errors.

However, the record itself is missing in Dynamics.  The record is nowhere to be found.  So the questions are:

1) Any theories (beside aliens) as to what might happened to the record that I got the GUID for?

2) How would want go about debugging such a thing considering that I don't have an access to the dynamic server itself?

3) What would be a good set of troubleshooting steps that the hosting service should perform to debug this issue (did you check that? or this?  etc.)?

```
public System.Guid Create(BusinessEntity entity) {
    object[] results = this.Invoke("Create", new object[] {
        entity});
        return ((System.Guid)(results[0]));
}
```

Comment: What type of entity are you creating? Beside aliens the most common issue are security restrictions preventing you from "seeing" records. You won't need access to the server itself since you can query records just like you create them. Which version of MS CRM are you targeting?

Comment: Thanks for fixing the formatting issues Filburt.  The version is CRM 4.0 (4.0.7333.2155).  I should have mentioned that I have access to the CRM DB via sql server management studio.  I am looking at the table where the record should be.  But it's not.  Yet I have a GUID.  Is there an API logs in Dynamics that I can tell the hosting folks to take a look?

Comment: I have to admit that I don't know CRM 4.0 and its SDK well enough to give much useful advice (but know 2011 quite well) but generally last resort for troubleshooting this would be asking your hosting service for turning on tracing in CRM to capture any errors that might happen during processing your newly created record.

Comment: the user used to connect the API it's the same user used by Web interface? did you try a Retrieve with the Guid after the Create is finished?

Comment: No.  Different user.  That's how I distinguish API calls with the regular users.  I currently don't do a Retrieve after the create - but do it before. I check for a record and if it's there, I update.  I suppose I could do that but at times we have a lot of records and that's one more trip to the server. It just bugs me that I get a GUID that with no exception.  I was sure that if I get a GUID then all is well. Another issue is that when I google this issue, there are no others cases with the same issue.  Which points the finger back at me that I'm missing something but I just don't what.

Comment: If you get a Guid from CRM the record created, if you don't populate the Guid it is generated by SQL Server meaning the CREATE call has to complete. Can you explain the code? It looks a little unusual. I would expect something like `Guid results = service.Create(businessEntity);`. Perhaps you could post the underlying code that makes up the `Invoke` method.

Comment: We have more than 1 environments and trust me sometimes it happens that we connect to 1st environment and create a record and searching for that record in the 2nd evnironment crm/sql db.  I think that is the problem

Comment: I just want to touch base and say that I'm still working on this and as soon as I have an answer I will update this post.  Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know of two probable causes:

**Scenario 1**

It is interesting you "are using a third-party MS Dynamics hosting". It probably means you are sharing the CRM Servers with other tenants (CRM organization databases). In these kind of environments problems can occur when plugins have not been designed to be thread-safe.

I have seen plugins that would actually garble data of concurrently processed requests. Sources of these errors can e.g. be autonumbering plugin products, shared by multiple tenants in the same deployment. Autonumbering plugins are typically triggered on the creation of records. It is not impossible your records ended up in another database.

**Scenario 2**

You have a workflow in your system that is triggered (directly or indirectly) by the creation of your record deleting your record. Asynchronous plugins can actually also be a suspect.

Asynchronous processes run outside the original transaction scope, so your code does not necessarily have to be aware of it.

Comment: Thanks you.  Very plausible.  I will update as soon as I know something.

Comment: We got working.  The hosting provider switched from the "internet" model to AD model by creating a tunnel from our environment to theirs.  There wasn't anything wrong on my side.  As such, even though they have no explanation as to why I as getting a GUID when the record was missing, I can only assume (without any hard proof) that Henk's Scenarios were the root cause.  Thanks again everyone.